# HTML and JavaScript - Incorrect POST output generated

Tags: javascript, html

Does anyone know why the following would not generate the expected POST output when submitted?

```
<tr>
   <td><input type="hidden" name="lawyer[1][OptimaID]" value="L7M"></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="lawyer[1][checkbox]" value="checked">
   <input type="hidden" name="lawyer[1][pmID]" value="3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>
      <select name="lawyer[2][OptimaID]">
         <option name="lawyer[2][OptimaID]" value="LSF">LS  - </option>
         <option name="lawyer[2][OptimaID]" value="L0J">Lom</option>
         <option name="lawyer[2][OptimaID]" value="L2J">Lm</option>
      </select>
   </td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="lawyer[2][checkbox]" value="checked">
   <input type="hidden" name="lawyer[2][pmID]" value="5"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input type="hidden" name="lawyer[3][OptimaID]" value="LS9"></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="lawyer[3][checkbox]" value="checked">
   <input type="hidden" name="lawyer[3][pmID]" value="6"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>
   <input type="hidden" name="lawyer[4][OptimaID]" value="L9"></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="lawyer[4][checkbox]" value="checked">
   <input type="hidden" name="lawyer[4][pmID]" value="1536146674"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>
      <select name="lawyer[5][OptimaID]">
         <option name="lawyer[5][OptimaID]" value="LSO-53648V">Vart.com</option>
         <option name="lawyer[5][OptimaID]" value="LSO-84359E">L06 - </option>
      </select>
   </td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="lawyer[5][checkbox]" value="checked">
   <input type="hidden" name="lawyer[5][pmID]" value="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>
   <input type="hidden" name="lawyer[6][OptimaID]" value="LR"></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="lawyer[6][checkbox]" value="checked">
   <input type="hidden" name="lawyer[6][pmID]" value="3"></td>
</tr>
```

I am getting:

```
lawyer[1][OptimaID] "value"
lawyer[1][pmID] "value"
lawyer[2][OptimaID] "value"
lawyer[2][pmID] "value"
lawyer[3][OptimaID] "value"
lawyer[3][pmID] "value"
lawyer[4][OptimaID] "value"
lawyer[4][pmID] "value"
lawyer[5][OptimaID] "value"
lawyer[5][pmID] "value"
lawyer[6][OptimaID] "value"
lawyer[6][pmID] "value"
```

Expecting:

```
lawyer = [
[
    'OptimaID' => 'val',
    'pmID' => 'val',
    'checkbox' => 'checked'
],
[
    'OptimaID' => 'Amira',
    'pmID' => 'Sayegh'
],
[
    'OptimaID' => 'Amira',
    'pmID' => 'Sayegh'
],
[
    'OptimaID' => 'val',
    'pmID' => 'val',
    'checkbox' => 'checked'
],
[
    'OptimaID' => 'Amira',
    'pmID' => 'Sayegh'
]
```

]

I tried:

- adding [] at the end of the name of each field
- added double quotes around the "OptimaID" and "pmID"
- starting the index at 0 and 1

Searched for all the html form name array and other posts such as: https://mattstauffer.com/blog/a-little-trick-for-grouping-fields-in-an-html-form/ but cant seem to see why my POST data is not grouping properly

Comment: What are you expecting instead? Note that only checked checkboxes are sent to the server.

Comment: `<option>` shouldn't have `name=`, although I don't think it causes any harm. They'll be ignored.

Comment: Expecting the following:
lawyer = [
    [
        'OptimaID' => 'val',
        'pmID' => 'val',
        'checkbox' => 'checked'
    ],
    [
        'OptimaID' => 'Amira',
        'pmID' => 'Sayegh'
    ],
    [
        'OptimaID' => 'Amira',
        'pmID' => 'Sayegh'
    ],
    [
        'OptimaID' => 'val',
        'pmID' => 'val',
        'checkbox' => 'checked'
    ],
 [
        'OptimaID' => 'Amira',
        'pmID' => 'Sayegh'
    ]
]

Comment: What middleware are you using to process the form parameters? PHP will do that in `$_POST['lawyer']`. Note that array indexes start at 0, not 1.

Comment: The square brackets are not interpreted on the front end by the form or in JavaScript for a normal POST request. If you are using PHP look at [Example #3](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php#example-99). Or are you going to handle the form values in JavaScript -- like doing a AJAX request/fetch and would like to use JSON?